# select query from mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

i want create multiple search where statement $where_search is a multiple condition from post form. 
but stil error when iam using this code ".where_search." in where condition with mysql_num_rows for paging

```
$tampil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search."  and kd_kelompok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' and nm_sebutan IS NOT NULL " );
```

this is the complete code.

```
$where_search = "kd_pok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' ";

if (isset($_POST['lakpus']))
{

    if (empty($_POST['lakpus']))
    {

    }
    else
    {

        if (empty($where_search))
        {
             $where_search .= "lakpus = '$lakpus' ";
        }
        else
        {

             $where_search .= "AND lakpus = '$lakpus' ";

        }
    }
} 

if (isset($_POST['kd_por']))
{
    $kd_por = $_POST['kd_por'] ;

    if (empty($_POST['kd_por']))
    {

    }
    else
    {

        if (empty($where_search))
        {
            $where_search .= "kd_por = '$kd_por' ";

        } 
        else
        {

            $where_search .= "AND tab1.kd_por = '$kd_por' ";

        }
    }
} 

$max=15;
$tampil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search."  and kd_kelompok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' and nm_sebutan IS NOT NULL " );
$jml = mysql_num_rows($tampil2);
$jmlhal  = ceil($jml/$max);
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and could potentially be broken by a well-trained chicken (this is no disrespect to you: it's just what tutorials teach, even in 2012). Use parameterized, prepared statements instead. You should use PDO or MySQLi instead of php_mysql, as it is _deprecated_.

Comment: This is an error code.... Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Okay. Before you run that function, `echo mysql_error();` and see what it results in, then post it :)

Comment: i had post with form and the result is Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource                                                                                                                                     i think iam wrong to write this code   '$tampil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search."  and kd_kelompok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' and nm_sebutan IS NOT NULL " );' look in where condition ".$where_search." is iam right writing the code ??

Comment: "not a valid result" means your query has a syntax error, and you've got no error handling at all. NEVER assume a query succeeded. always check the return values from mysql operations for failure. Even if the query statement is 100% valid, there's way too many OTHER reasons for failure.

Comment: i have succed with this code `$qry = "SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search; $res = mysql_query($qry); $row = mysql_fetch_array($res); $num = mysql_num_rows($res);` but there is an error when iam use mysql_num_rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your error is here:

```
$where_search .= "AND tab1.kd_por = '$kd_por' ";
```

Because you didn't declare the "tab1". Try change to this:

```
$where_search .= "AND kd_por = '$kd_por' ";
```

**EDIT 1**

You didn't recovery the var `$lakpus` from `$_POST` befofe use it. Here is part of the code that you have to update.

```
...

else
{

    $lakpus = $_POST['lakpus'];

    if (empty($where_search))
    {
        $where_search .= "lakpus = '$lakpus' ";
    }

    ...
```

**EDIT 2**

As i said in the comments, try to call mysql_num_rows() after mysql_query(), like below.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search; 

$res = mysql_query($qry); 

$num = mysql_num_rows($res);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Comment: yes that right iam wrong to write but the problem is in $tampil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search." and kd_kelompok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' and nm_sebutan IS NOT NULL " );  look in where condition ".$where_search." is iam right writing the code ??

Comment: i have writen var in the begining of code... but when iam write this code manually without multiple search condition its work.... `$tampil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bb where kd_lakpus='$_POST[lakpus] and kd_por='$_POST[kd_por]' and kd_kelompok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' and nm_sebutan IS NOT NULL " );`    that code is manual without var search

Comment: @AndiNugroho, Please echo the var `$where_search` before  you run mysql_quer() and tell me what you get

Comment: i have succed with this code `  $qry = "SELECT * FROM bb where ".$where_search; $res = mysql_query($qry);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  $num = mysql_num_rows($res); ` but there is an error when iam use mysql_num_rows

Comment: @AndiNugroho, Try to call mysql_num_rows() before mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: i have echo $where_search before run mysql_query is `kd_pok='2' and kd_komoditi='11' and lakpus='46' and kd_por='46xxxx'`

Comment: @AndiNugroho, I said to call mysql_num_rows() before mysql_fetch_array(), not to echo de `$where_search`

Comment: @AndiNugroho, I've done a new edit, please see it. As i said, mysql_num_rows() should come after mysql_query()